# Would a question about switching to the mobile verison of Bing be acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I am wanting to ask a question about how to return from the desktop version of Bing to the mobile verison of Bing on my iPhone. Here is the full text of my proposed question:

> I started using Bing on my iPhone and thought it worked well enough
>   with the mobile site. However, I couldn't find a way to log in so that
>   I could start getting credit for Bing Rewards, so I clicked the link
>   to switch to the desktop version of the website. I was able to
>   succesfully log in at the point.
>
> But now, I can't figure out how to return to the mobile site. I don't
>   see any links on the desktop page of Bing. The
>   home page (the one with the pretty image that changes each day) and
>   the Settings page appear to be optimized for mobile use, but neither
>   has an option to make the whole site like that.
>
> I assume that I'm not stuck using the desktop site forever, so
>   how can I return to the mobile site?

Would a question like this be appropriate on this site?

This site has a Bing tag that has a number of questions, so it seems like general Bing questions are on topic. However, this is using Bing in relation to a mobile version of the website which would mean I'm on a smart phone, and I know that questions on smart phones are generally frowned upon.

I noticed that Ask Different (the Apple Stack Exchange) doesn't have any questions on Bing (not surprisingly as it doesn't really have anything to do with an iPhone as it's just using Bing's website) and there doesn't seem to be a "website super user" Stack Exchange.

So does this question belong here and, if not, where would it belong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be. Questions about mobile devices are only appropriate for Super User when they are about *interfacing* with a PC.

Questions about web services should go on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), questions about your iPhone should go on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).